# Select a row in dgv

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I made an usercontrol with a datagridview! 
I know how to select a row, add delete, these stuffs. I need to use the event selectionchanged, but talking without using usercontrol. 
The problem here, I cannot select the datagridview and the choose the event selectionchanged because I am using an usercontrol. Does anyone know how can I select a row in dgv which is in an usercontrol?

Thanks in advance!
This is what I have in the user control

```
Private Sub grid1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grid1.SelectionChanged
        Dim index As Integer
        Dim selectedrow As DataGridViewRow
        If Not grid1.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then
            Index = grid1.CurrentRow.Index
            selectedrow = grid1.Rows(Index)

        End If
    End Sub
```

And in the project I am trying to get some values from the row and cell.

```
Me.UcList1.tbName = "tblPeople"
        lblIDPeople.Text = Me.UcList1.grid1.selectedrow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

UPDATE

```
Me.UcList1.tbName = "tblPeople"
        If Not Me.UcList1.grid1.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then
            lblIDPeople.Text = Me.UcList1.selectedrow.Cells(0).Value.ToSring
        End If
```

Comment: From the designer of the user control, you can handle the `SelectionChanged` event.

Comment: @preciousbetine Ooh...thanks! But I gotta a question, What if in this dgv I want to get the cell 0 for example...and then I use the same user control but populate with another table, and get the another cell 5 for example. The code is the one that I edit it..Thanks

Comment: What do you get with the code above?

Comment: @preciousbetine it says that selectedrow is not a member of datagridview

Comment: Declare `selectedrow` as `Public selectedrow As DataGridViewRow` outside the `SelectionChanged Event`

Comment: @preciousbetine   Still did not work.. I mean...the problem is in the project, I think I am calling wrong stuffs there `Me.UcList1.grid1.selectedrow.Cells(0).Value.ToString`

Comment: @preciousbetine Ooh..I think I am putting this on the load event...

Comment: Move it out of the load event, what do you get?

Comment: @preciousbetine I updated my code...I tried to do that...but gets nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I tested it and its working

1. In the usercontrol, make the code look like this

   ```
   Public Class MyControl
       Public selectedrow As DataGridViewRow

       Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
           selectedrow = DataGridView1.CurrentRow
       End Sub
   End Class
   ```
2. In the main form, call it like this

   ```
   Public Class Form1

       Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

       End Sub

       Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
           If (Not MyControl1.selectedrow Is Nothing) Then
              MsgBox(MyControl1.selectedrow.Cells(1).Value)
              'lblIDPeople.Text = Me.MyControl1.Datagridview1.selectedrow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
           End If
       End Sub
   End Class
   ```

[image: Output]

Comment: I mean! it worked, but what if I want to change the value of the row and cell by only clicking at the row in the datagridview, not with a button. Anyway! Thanks a lot for your effort and time helping me.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I don't get what you mean by *change the value by clicking at the row in the datagridview*.

Comment: sorry that I am a little confusing to explaing. So I have a datagridview right? When I click in the row, I want that it returns me the ID of the row, which automatically does it as soon as select the row, using the event selectionchanged. But with the user control, I am having trouble on doing this. It loads with the selecting the first row, so it returns to me the right ID, but when I select another row, nothings happens. And I want to use this User control on at least 2 different tables, so thats why I have to put on the main form which cell look for the ID.